# Java regular expression: Matches back slash character

Tags: java, regex

How to macth a backslah (\) in java regular expression? I hava some sript to matching all latex tag  In some file but it didnt work.

```
public class TestMatchTag {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String tag = "\begin";

        if (Pattern.matches("\\\\[a-z]+", tag)) {
            System.out.println("MATCH");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace `String tag = "\begin";` with `String tag = "\\begin";`. The regex is valid, but your input string needs to escape `\` character.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
Pattern.matches("[\\a-z]+", tag)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need another backslash to escape the "\" in "\begin", change it to "\begin", otherwise the "\b" in your "\begin" will be considered as one character.

Answer (score -1):

This should work...

```
Pattern.matches("\\[a-z]+", tag);
```

[a-z] allows any character between a-z more than once and \\ allows "\" once.

you can validate your expression online [here](http://www.regexr.com/)